# JWST Sunshield tensioning

Tags: james-webb-telescope

I've just noticed the JWST sunshield temps have changed. The hot side is hotter and the cold side colder. Is the sunshield tensioning underway?

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57549/12102) covers this nicely.

Comment: [Not yet; tensioning is now scheduled to start on Jan 2nd](https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/2022/01/01/webb-sunshield-tensioning-to-begin-tomorrow/)